# Unstretchable Dough problem

Tags: baking

What could be the problem of mixed dough( maida, baking powder, salt, butter and cool water) refusal to stretch? I.e it's not stretching out at all. It's just stayed like bread crumbs . Please how can I save such a dough? Urgent help needed.
Thank you

Comment: Did you use a recipe? How much flour and water?

Comment: Is the problem that you mixed a dough that is stiff and will tear rather than stretch, or is it a problem of ingredients that won't come together into a dough, staying a paste that comes apart easily?  Your question can suggest either, and they will have different causes and answers.

Comment: how did you mix it (hand kneading, hand/stand mixer with dough hooks, hand mixer with whisks, food processor, blender)? Every of these methods will give different textures. Doughs are NOT just plain mixtures, or watery suspensions/solutions of ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

It stayed like bread crumbs? After you mixed all your ingredients together fully? If you added water, and your product is like bread crumbs (separate small particles that do not stick together), then you did not add enough water. I would not even call it dough until you can clump it together into a cohesive ball of material which you can then roll out, pat out into a flat patty, shape or manipulate in some way.

There may also be other problems with your dough than just not enough water. If you list the actual quantities of the ingredients you used, and say what sort of finished product you are trying for, people will be able to give you more precise advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't list the ingredient amounts, but it looks like a dough which is not supposed to stretch. It looks very much like a pie crust or shortbread (I can't tell you the exact type if you don't list the method), and this type of dough is indeed crumbly and has to be rolled out patiently.

You also don't say what you are baking at all. If you are intending to make a loaf, you probably chose the wrong recipe. Again, not entirely sure, as you did not mention amounts. You can probably bake a soda bread with this if you have enough water, but the dough for soda bread is not supposed to be stretchy either.